# How to query a Sharepoint 2010 List from Winform Application?

Tags: vb.net, linq, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-list

What is the easiest route to query a SharePoint 2010 list from a VB.Net Windows Forms application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the .NET client object model, as documented by Microsoft [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee537247(v=office.14).aspx), you can write C# or VB.Net code to access SharePoint.

Microsoft has provided [a walkthrough](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg277498(v=office.14).aspx) that shows you how to add the required assemblies to your project.

Here's the relevant excerpt:

> In your project, add references to the two required assemblies that compose the .NET client object model. These two assembles (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll and Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll) are located in the ISAPI folder of %ProgramFiles%\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\14.

Once you have the assemblies loaded, you can use the SharePoint client object model objects to retrieve information as documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee539350(v=office.14).aspx). For example:

> ## How to retrieve objects
>
> The following example shows how to load an object to access its properties. Because the list object is loaded in place, all default properties of the list can be accessed.
>
> ```
> Dim clientContext As New ClientContext("http://MyServer/sites/MySiteCollection")
> Dim oWebsite As Web = clientContext.Web
> Dim collList As ListCollection = oWebsite.Lists
>
> Dim oList As List = collList.GetByTitle("Announcements")
>
> clientContext.Load(oList)
>
> clientContext.ExecuteQuery()
>
> Console.WriteLine("Title: {0} Created: {1}", oList.Title, oList.Created)
> ```

Refer to the links above for more in-depth documentation.